# Появляются пустые строки при просмотре .csv файла

Tags: python, csv

При заполнение файла, при большом кол-ве элементов появляются пустые строки, хотя в списке элемент присутствует, возможно ли решить проблему без подключения доп. библиотек и без удаления пустой строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import csv
import random


def generation(countRow):
    def randomTrain(arTrain):
        idTrain = random.randint(1, 99999)
        if idTrain not in arTrain:
            arTrain.append(idTrain)
            return idTrain
        else:
            randomTrain(arTrain)

    with open("tester.csv", 'w', newline="") as csv_file:
        # head = ["Город", "Номер", "Время"]
        head = ["id"]
        file_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";", lineterminator="\r")
        file_writer.writerow(head)
        haveCount = 1
        newAr = []
        while haveCount != countRow:
            file_writer.writerow([randomTrain(newAr)])
            haveCount += 1
    #print(newAr)

generation(1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        else:
            randomTrain(arTrain)
```

В этом случае функция ничего не вернёт, то есть вернёт `None`. А судя по всему нужно, чтобы при заходе в рекурсию функция возвращала её результат:

```
        else:
            return randomTrain(arTrain)
            ^^^^^^
```

А вообще лучше всегда делать без рекурсии. Например, так:

```
    def randomTrain(arTrain):
        while True:
            idTrain = random.randint(1, 99999)
            if idTrain not in arTrain:
                arTrain.append(idTrain)
                return idTrain
```